# Collect the multiple of one determinant?

Tags: matrix, formatting

```
m = {{2, 6, 4}, {2, 6, 5}, {-3, 6, 6}};
```

Consider I'm doing calculation by hand.

I want to collect the multiple 6 of second column, how to do that?

I'd like the result something like the following. The main purpose is to show the solution steps(in Notebook or Latex)

$$\begin{align*}det(m)=6~det\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 2& 1 & 4 \\ 2 & 1 & 5 \\ -3 & 1 & 6 \\\end{array}\right);\end{align*}$$

Maybe something `collect[m]` function, and generate all possible results?

or

$$\begin{align*}det(m)=2~det\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 3& 2\\ 2 & 6& 5 \\ -3 & 6& 6 \\\end{array}\right);\end{align*}$$

Comment: @Nasser Maybe something `collect[m]` function, and generate all possible results?

Comment: Do you know how to multiply matrices by scalars? Your expectation is not compatibile with standard conventions but rather completely unnatural.

Comment: @Artes multiply matrices is not the same as multiply a determinant?

Comment: @Nasser sorry, I need your comments, they are useful to improve my question.

Comment: @HyperGroups If you need a determinant you should explicitely write $det(matrix)$

Comment: @Artes ok, I mentioned  determinant in the title, let me add it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in two steps:

```
m={{1,6,4},{2,6,5},{-3,6,6}};
MatrixForm[Apply[Times,GCD@@@m]] * MatrixForm[rm= (#/GCD@@#)&/@m ]
MatrixForm[Apply[Times,GCD@@@Transpose[rm]]] * MatrixForm[Transpose[(#/GCD@@#)&/@Transpose[rm]] ]
```

in one step:

```
MatrixForm[Apply[Times,GCD@@@m]  *
 Apply[Times,GCD@@@Transpose[(#/GCD@@#)&/@m]]] * MatrixForm[Transpose[(#/GCD@@#)&/@Transpose[(#/GCD@@#)&/@m] ]]
```

Comment: Welcome to SE! `GCD` is a good idea.